# rails: how can we add multiple valued params in db in one query in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Consider I have these attributes in table: `answers`, `user_id`, `question_id`

This is what I did:

I stored it with the loop but that's bad practice to trigger database again and again:

```
temp= params.fetch(:user_answer)
temp["answers"].length.times { |i|
  UserAnswer.create!(answers: temp["answers"][i], question_id: temp["question_id"][i], student_id: current_user.id)
}
```

I have values in my params like this:

```
"user_answer"=>{"answers"=>["C++ is mother of all the languages", "25"], "question_id"=>["7", "10"], "student_id"=>["12", "12"]}
```

How can I add multiple records in one query with this params?

Comment: What is the data type of these attributes?  eg is 'answers' a string or an array of strings?

Comment: May be is better send such params from frontend: `{"user_answer"=>[{"answers"=>"a1", "question_id"=>1, "student_id"=>1}, {"answers"=>"a2", "question_id"=>2, "student_id"=>2}]}`

Comment: how can we send such params?

Comment: answers is a string its bassically a single answer for the specific question

Answer (score 0):

You can pass to [`create`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create) array of arguments

But firstly you need to create such array

```rb
user_answer_args =
  params[:user_answer].each_with_object([]) do |(param, values), args|
    values.each_with_index do |value, index|
      args[index] ||= {}
      args[index].merge!(param => value)
    end
  end
```

And than

```rb
UserAnswer.create(user_answer_args)
```

Note: you need to convert params to hash firstly, something like this

```rb
user_answer_params =
  params.
    require(:user_answer).
    permit(answers: [], question_id: [], student_id: []).
    to_h
```